# How do you add an examples table to a background in a cucumber feature file?

Tags: cucumber

I'm wanting to add an examples table to a background step in a cucumber feature file. How do I go about doing this?

I want to do something like this:

```
Background:
Given <username> has logged in

Examples:
|username|
|User 1  |
|User 2  |

Scenario: .....
```

Comment: AFAIK I don't think it's possible. Imagine you have 1 table in your background, then each scenario sharing this background also has 1 Outline table, then it would be exponential.

Comment: I do stuck with the same requirement.
any solution on this?

Comment: @PriyaP did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

The Cucumber [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you..

```
Feature: Passing background with multiline args 

Background: 
Given table |a|b| 
|c|d|
And multiline string """ I'm a cucumber
and I'm okay. I sleep all night and I test all day """

Scenario: passing background

Then the table should be 
|a|b| 
|c|d| 

Then the multiline string should be """ I'm a cucumber and I'm okay. I sleep all night and I test all day 

""" Scenario: another passing background 

Then the table should be |a|b| |c|d| 

Then the multiline string should be """ I'm a cucumber and I'm okay. I sleep all night and I test all day
```

Refer this link for more scenarios..

https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/gherkin/background

Answer (score -4):

May be this could help you:

```
Background:
    Given Login with email myemail@mail.com and pass myPass

Scenario Outline:Scenario 1

Examples:
  | thing1| thing2 | thing3 |
  | fdlsk | fadsff | faskld |
```

And in your stepdef use this:

```
@Then("^Login Login with email ([^\"]*) and pass ([^\"]*)$")
    public void login_general(String email, String pass) {
            login.fillEmail(email);
            login.fillPass(pass);
            login.clickLogin();
    }
```

Comment: This isn't answering the question, as the user was asking about variables in the `Background` section - your example isn't referencing the example table at all. Unfortunately, it seems the OP isn't possible.